# How to hide an specific line in popup

Tags: html, css

this is the code of the website:

```
<div class="infoBox" style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; width: 450px; left: 504.626px; top: -103.94px;">

<div class="marker-wrapper animated fadeInDown">
    <div class="marker-title"></div>
    <div class="marker-content">
        <div class="two_third popup-content">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li>
                    <span class="icon-link"></span>
                    <a href="http://www.hotelesavant.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="one_third last image-wrapper pop-image"></div>
```

And writing this on custom CSS, hides whole popup box:

```
.popup-content ul li {
margin-bottom: 5px;
color: #5A5A5A;
}
```

But I want to hide only this:

```
<li>
  <span class="icon-link"></span>
  <a href="http://www.hotelesavant.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"></a>
</li>
```

Best Regards... and thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use last-child:

```
.popup-content ul li:last-child { display:none;}
```

**EDIT:**  If the 'LI' element in question will end up not being the last li, than you're other option is to use:

```
li:nth-child(#index of the element)
```

in your case:

```
li:nth-child(1)
```

unless of course you can add a class to it.

Comment: The problem with this is when you want to hide something that is **not** the last child.

Comment: @user1206365 If the 'li' element will end up not being the last li, than you're other option is to use li:nth-child(#index of the element), unless ofcourse you can add a class to it :)

Comment: Sorry if I touch a nerve but this is a not-so-specific case and the goal of the site is to provide actual useful answers to help other people lean, not just correct the code that they upload. You may want to edit your answer and add what you describe in your last comment, I think it may help him more than a class (I didn't even know you could write selectors like that).

Comment: @arielnmz I'm not that touchy ;) I will update my answer.. though your comment seems out of place... I did not correct the OP's code, I think I did help since the solution worked, and I do hope people can learn from it, even you.

Answer (score 0):

Give an `id` or a `class` to your li and set it's `visibility` property to either `hidden` or `collapse`:

```
<li class="hide">
  <span class="icon-link"></span>
  <a href="http://www.hotelesavant.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"></a>
</li>

.hide {
    visibility: collapse;
}
```

I suggest `collapse` over `hidden` because it will not even occupy the space it would use instead of just rendering it *transparent*. The advantage of the `visibility` property is that you can not only make it disappear, but you can just make it transparent if you want to preserve the space it would occupy.

Comment: It is just an example, of course you should have to implement this approach on your own code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `adjacent sibling selector` `'+'`

```
.icon-link + a {
    display: none;
}
```